# calendar issue in asp.net while typing date

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

> Currently when the user types in the shortened version (06/05/17) it
>   automatically defaults to (06/05/0017) rather than selecting it by Calender.

**it should be 06/05/2017**
**if  user write 06/05/87 it should be 06/05/2087**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" MaxLength="10" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<span class="input-group-addon calendar-icon" id="FromCalSpan"><i class="fa fa-calendar">
</i></span>
```

Comment: Try using `Calendar` class: `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.ToFourDigitYear` together with `Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2099`; or use client-side `fixYear` method.

Comment: can i write CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.ToFourDigitYear in aspx ?

Comment: Use Calendar control - basicdatepicker instead

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure user is going to enter year above 2000 .you can just split the string and add 2000 to the last splited string

```
 private void txtFromDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] words;
            if (txtFromDate.Text.Contains("/"))
            {
                words = txtFromDate.Text.Split("/");
            }

            words[2] = (int.Parse(words[2].ToString()) + 2000).ToString();

            txtFromDate.Text = words[0].ToString() + "/" + words[1].ToString() + "/" + words[2].ToString();
        }
```

I had done it in codebehind as you had not mentioned Webform or MVC .But I strongly recomend using javascript for both

Comment: Then try this in codebehind it will work or if you are good in javascript do it for best  user experience

Answer (score 0):

You can use either server-side or client-side approach to resolve 2 digit year conversion as shown below, including simple check against date length:

**a. Server side**

This approach utilizes [`Calendar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar(v=vs.110).aspx) class in `System.Globalization` namespace, which will convert date input to 4 digit year.

```
protected void txtFromDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String date = txtFromDate.Text;
    String[] digits = date.Split('/');

    var culture = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
    culture.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2099; // 4 digits range between 2000 & 2099

    int fourDigitYear = culture.Calendar.ToFourDigitYear(Convert.ToInt32(digits[2]));

    // uses 4 digit year if the text field has 10 characters (2 digits day, 2 digits month, 2 date separators & 4 digits year)
    if (date.Length == 10)
    {
        fourDigitYear = digits[2];
    }

    txtFromDate.Text = words[0].ToString() + "/" + words[1].ToString() + "/" + fourDigitYear;
}
```

**b. Client side**

This jQuery approach uses plain string concatenation with standard `Date` methods. Note that `month` in JS started by index 0 (for January) instead of 1, thus requires subtraction and addition process during date adjustment.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("<%= txtFromDate.ClientID %>").change(function () {
            var data = $(this).val();
            var len = data.length; // check if it's 2 digits or 4 digits year
            var day = data.substr(0, 2);
            var month = data.substr(3, 2) - 1;
            var year = 0;
            if (len == 8) {
                year = parseInt("20" + data.substr(6, 2));
            } else {
                year = parseInt(data.substr(6, 4));
            }

            var date = new Date(year, month, day);

            $(this).val(date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear());
        });
    });
</script>
```